# changed the repository name on github and website which is on goddady is not updating

Tags: git, github, dns, host

So I have a github account and I have a domain name from goddady. I had to change the repo name and once I changed it my website does not reflect any changes. I can see the commit and new files on github but not on the actual website. What am I missing in here?

Answer (score 0):

A little context may be useful here.

Is this referring to Github Pages feature, whereby Github is basically serving up your site ?

If so, to use a domain name for this site, there is some setup required to have it served from your Github Pages site. In short, there is some DNS configuration to be done on your domain registrar (GoDaddy) and some configuration to add this domain name in github. See https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/